# Saying the blessing before counting the Omer

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

If you have counted the Omer every night but did not say the blessing can you start to say the blessing now?

Answer (score 2):

If you should've been saying the blessing all along, then having missed saying it until now is no reason not to start now, provided you haven't also missed counting. Sources: the implication of [*Mishna B'rura* 489:35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=194), who says "did not bless" means "did not count"; and the general rule that skipping a blessing before a mitzvah does not detract from having fulfilled the mitzvah, which is the question at hand when deciding whether to continue reciting the blessing on counting.

As to whether you should've been saying the blessing all along, that depends, for example, [on whether you're male, according to some authorities](/q/6970/170).